# Steam won't launch after it updated, on 20.04.1

Tags: steam

Every time I try to launch Steam, it opens the "updating steam" window and stops immediately after.

I tried fully reinstalling multiple times, nothing works.

When I try to run it from the terminal I get this:

```
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
/home/USER/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam
[2020-10-10 11:55:02] Startup - updater built Oct  7 2020 06:15:36
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1602115886)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  45
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request:  46
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2020-10-10 11:55:03] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2020-10-10 11:55:03] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2020-10-10 11:55:03] 1. http://client-download.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 100, source = 'baked in'
[2020-10-10 11:55:03] 2. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1602115886)
[2020-10-10 11:55:03] Checking for update on startup
[2020-10-10 11:55:03] Checking for available updates...
[2020-10-10 11:55:03] Downloading manifest: client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1602115886)
[2020-10-10 11:55:03] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1602115886, installed version 1602115886, downloaded version 0
[2020-10-10 11:55:03] Nothing to do
[2020-10-10 11:55:03] Verifying installation...
[2020-10-10 11:55:03] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2020-10-10 11:55:03] Verification complete
Loaded SDL version 2.0.13-5919606
Gtk-Message: 11:55:03.958: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 11:55:03.958: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(steam:6881): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:55:03.960: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-2.0/main.rc:775: error: unexpected identifier 'direction', expected character '}'

(steam:6881): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:55:03.962: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-2.0/hacks.rc:28: error: invalid string constant "normal_entry", expected valid string constant
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Serial number of failed request:  48
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  47
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Serial number of failed request:  49
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
assert_20201010115502_1.dmp[6904]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20201010115502_1.dmp
/home/USER/.steam/debian-installation/steam.sh : ligne 750 :  6881 Erreur de segmentation  (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
```

I can't make sense of it, what am I missing here that could make it run again ?

Comment: "Failed to load driver" is where I'd start looking.

Comment: Ok I'm an idiot, reinstalled the nvidia drivers and everything is running smooth. Thanks !

Comment: Hey Jules Chauvin! Do answer your own question. It'll be helpful to the community :) https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

After hours of figuring out and searching on internet.

What I did, I install **Software & Updates** App . Then Open Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers Tab -> NVDIA Corporation -> Using NVIDIA Driver ... (properietary,tested) then **apply changes** .

I restarted my computer afterwards and it works perfectly.